# WPF: Implementing and binding (datagrid) to a custom collection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, collections

I have a custom collection that I am passing to a WPF client, which is binding the collection to a `datagrid` using `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`. The datagrid, however, is displaying empty rows (albeit the right number of empty rows). What am I doing wrong? Following is some sample code. For now I've omitted everything having to do with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` because, well, I first want to have some data showing up in the grid.

I should also mention that I've tried implementing the above two interfaces, but they seem to have nothing to do with this issue.

(You might not actually want to look at the sample code as there's absolutely nothing interesting about it. The collection implementation is just wrapping an inner List.)

Some random POCO:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Simple collection implementation:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : IList<T>
{
    private List<T> list = new List<T>();

    public MyCollection()
    {
    }

    public MyCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        list.AddRange(collection);
    }

 #region ICollection<T> Members

    public void Add(T item)
    {
       list.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
       list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return list.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
       list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
       get { return list.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
       return list.Remove(item);
    }

#endregion

#region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }

#endregion

#region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

#endregion

#region IList<T> Members

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return list.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
       list.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
       list.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
       get { return list[index]; }
       set { list[index] = value; }
    }

   #endregion
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfCustomCollection.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The window's code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     MyCollection<Person> persons = new MyCollection<Person>()
     {
         new Person(){FirstName="john", LastName="smith"},
         new Person(){FirstName="foo", LastName="bar"}
     };

     dataGrid1.DataContext = persons;
}
```

By the way, if you change the code-behind to use a List<Person> instead of the MyCollection<Person>, everything works as expected.

EDIT:

The above code is not taken from the real situation. I have only posted it to show what I am doing in order to test my problem and to make it easier to replicate it. **The actual custom collection object is quite complex and I cannot post it here**. Again, I'm just trying to understand the basic concept behind what needs to be done in order for a datagrid to properly bind to a custom collection and automatically generate columns for the underlying objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, in order for AutoGenerateColumns to work in a WPF `DataGrid`, your collection has to implement [IItemProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iitemproperties.aspx), although I've found that wrapping my collection in a (windows forms) BindingList does the trick as well (it actually wraps your collection, unlike the `ObservableCollection` which just copies your collections' members into itself).

Answer (score 3):

What is your `MyCollection<T>` type adding over `List<T>`?  Either way, I would use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead (so that the UI is notified of additions/removals), and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `Person` class so that the UI is notified of changes to that type's property values.

**EDIT**

I don't think it's particularly trivial binding to your own custom collection type.  You'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` on that type.  This article might be of some use - http://www.e-pedro.com/2009/04/creating-a-custom-observable-collection-in-wpf/

Another option if you are using MVVM, is to use your custom collection type on your model, and use a standard `ObservableCollection` on your view model and populate your view models collection from your model, then bind your grid to your view models collection.

Comment: Sorry, I probably was not clear in my question. The MyCollection object was only intended to describe the problem. The actual custom-collection I'm using is completely different. I'm just trying to understand how to make this work. Will update the question.

Comment: Funny, all roads just lead to that same article. I did, in fact, follow the directions of the article you linked to. And that led me to the phenomenon I mentioned in the question. As for using the view-model as an intermediary, that's exactly what I wanted to avoid by implementing my own collection. That IS the current implementation, but I want to reduce the amount of binding code going on. Also, I purposefully wanted to avoid the topic of INotify___ because I first want to see that the AutoGenerateColumns works in the datagrid.

Answer (score 3):

I think you using your knowlege of Windows Forms by writing
    dataGrid1.DataContext = persons;
 In WPF DataGrid is connected to the collection (say List) very simple:
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = persons;